# How to make a nav items to adapt to small screen size

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to make nav items adaptive to the smaller screens.  I have tried to give to parent element max-width 100% but it doesn't work. It only works when I turn display: flex; off. I need nav items to be restricted by a parent widht.

I have the following code :

### HTML

```html
<nav class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab active">
            All
            <span class="badge grey">151</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            Started
            <span class="badge grey">128</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            On Hold
            <span class="badge grey">15</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            Completed
            <span class="badge grey">8</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</nav>
```

### CSS:

```css
    .tabs {
      display: flex;
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      gap: 1.5rem;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    .tabs > * {
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab {
      padding: 1rem 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 0.5rem;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab.active {
      color: var(--color-heading);
    }
    
    .tabs .tab.active::after {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: var(--color-primary);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    }
```

So in this image you may see the result I am trying to achieve but without turning the flex off:

[image]

Comment: So for smaller screen sizes, you want that `Completed` does not appear at all, instead of only showing partially.

Comment: @t.niese. On a smaller screens there is overflow-x is auto and scroll is available. I just need them to adapt to smaller screens.

Comment: And how should they adapt to smaller screen size? What should happen? Form the image this is not really clear to me. And how should that change be tied to the width?

Comment: @t.niese, I want tabs to adapt their width to parent width and every time when I am making the screen narrower, it should change its width. In the picture above, we see the behavior I need to achieve, but for this, I had to turn the display flex off, however I need this behavior with display flex included.  There is an overflow-x  and on a smaller screens when there is no enough space tabs are scrolled. Hope it clarifies. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `@media (max-width: ...)` and there decrease `padding`, `font-size`, etc to get wanted result

Answer (score 0):

The flex will force all elements to be on the same row. You can use `flex-wrap` to let items optionally go to the next row.

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
  gap: 1.5rem;
- flex-wrap: nowrap;
+ flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

You can also choose to optionally set `flex-direction: column` for small screens using MichaelLearner's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the flex items to show in a different way on a big streen than on a small screen, consider changing the direction of the boxes from row (default to column:

Desktop:

```
.tabs { /* for desktop monitors with lots of with */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
}
```

Mobile:

```
.tabs { /* for thin tall mobile phones */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
```

```css
   .tabs {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;  /* setting this to row or column will change the flow of boxes */
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      gap: 1.5rem;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    
    .tabs > * {
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab {
      padding: 1rem 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 0.5rem;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .tabs .tab.active {
      color: var(--color-heading);
    }
    
    .tabs .tab.active::after {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: var(--color-primary);
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab active">
            All
            <span class="badge grey">151</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            Started
            <span class="badge grey">128</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            On Hold
            <span class="badge grey">15</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="tab">
            Completed
            <span class="badge grey">8</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</nav>
```

*PS. It appears you were trying to insert an image? (first line) please copy paste it again, directly into the editor. Stack Overflow allows for that! Also, please add what you exactly want to see in the answer.*

Comment: so, my task is to make them take parents' width.  and while I am making the screen smaller they also get narrower. Changing their flex direction to the column is not an option.